# Design recommendations required for a multi-threaded queue based file syn app

Tags: c#, multithreading, queue

I am developing an application using C# which is supposed to sync files from a user's computer with a remote storage area.

I think application should have following key modules:

- The Processing Engine
- Thread Pool
- Queue Manager
- File System Watch

As soon as a new file is detected in a folder, File System Watch should be able to put a work item in Queue Manager. Queue Manager should be able to persist the item in some sort of permanent storage media so that even if Processing Engine is not running, we should not miss anything.

Now, as soon as something is placed inside Queue, Processing Engine should get notification. It should use a thread pool to kick start the actual job. Queue Manager should be able to set the status of a work item as 'being-under-processing' or 'done'.

User should be able to set how many simultaneous threads shall be used for processing.

Now, I need help in identifying correct API's... or some open-source components.

For Thread Pooling, I am thinking about using Smart Thread Pool ( http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/smartthreadpool.aspx ).

For rest, I need help.

Plus, any recommendations in improving the application style would be appreciated.

Cheers;

Answer (score 1):

I think you can save some time using this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb887623

More details:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb902860.aspx

EDIT - after comment about REST sotrage requirement:

you can make use of the framework and implement/plugin custom providers to account for that... see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617372.aspx

Comment: Seems like interesting bed-time read. But this does not solve my problem. I need to sync files with a remote storage which is exposed via REST interface;

Comment: It still can solve the problem because you can implement/plugin custom providers - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617372.aspx